# align three td's in single tr of table

Tags: css

I am trying to put three td's inside a tr.the thing is that first td should be centered and another two td's should be aligned to left I mean they have to display the text after the first td.please see the jsfiddle of sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/srinivas2828/6S5wj) ,
i want text2,text3,text4 should display after the text1 and can anybody help me i how can i do that?

```
    <table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td style="padding-top:7px;height=10px;padding-left:37.5%;">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" width="100%">text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>text5
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what your desired result is. Isn't this just a case of re-structuring your HTML? I.E: http://jsfiddle.net/6S5wj/10/

Answer (score 0):

Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/kqHLv/) what you are looking for?

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">text5
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply ,this in not the exact one i am looking for but it helped  some what,text1 should be exactly at the centre of the screen and text2,text3 and trext4 should come next to the text2 with out any spacing.